# Detect if GoBack() was called in NavigationContext

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, prism

In a view that implements IConfirmNavigationRequest I am using four navigation transition animations: ForwardIn, ForwardOut, BackwardIn, and BackwardOut.

I'm using the ConfirmNavigationRequest to wait for the Out transition to finish before navigating.  But, depending on the type of navigation - forward using RequestNavigate() or backward using GoBack() - I want to play different storyboards:

```
    public void ConfirmNavigationRequest(NavigationContext navigationContext, Action<bool> continuationCallback)
    {
        Storyboard storyboard;

        if (navigationContext./* was RequestNavigate() or GoBack() called? */)
        {
            // GoBack navigation request.
            storyboard = ((Storyboard)FindResource(RegionTransitions.BackwardOut));
        }
        else
        {
            // Forward navigation request.
            storyboard = ((Storyboard)FindResource(RegionTransitions.ForwardOut));
        }

        storyboard.Completed += (sender, args) => continuationCallback(true);
        storyboard.Begin();
    }
```

Is there any accurate and predictable way to detect which type of navigation was used from the NavigationContext?

Edit:  I've since abandoned using IConfirmNavigation for transitions and am now using an AnimatedContentControl.

I don't really like it, but I'm publishing an event to 'warn' the AnimatedContentControl that the next navigation should use a specific transition:

```
_eventAggregator.GetEvent<RegionTransitionEvent>().Publish(new RegionTransitionEventArgs { RegionName = RegionNames.NavRegion, RegionTransition = RegionTransitions.BackwardIn });

_regionManager.RequestNavigate(RegionNames.ContentRegion, ViewNames.ABC);
```

Comment: Do you find a solution for your problem. I also want to know if the navigation results from a back navigation?

Answer (score 1):

You can implement the `INavigationAware` interface in your view or viewmodel.

This interface will implement 3 methods.

```
public interface INavigationAware
{
    void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationContext navigationContext);
    bool IsNavigationTarget(NavigationContext navigationContext);
    void OnNavigatedFrom(NavigationContext navigationContext);
}
```

the will allow you to determine if it is navigation to and from somewhere. you can even determine of which view the navigation comes from.

Comment: Thanks, but IConfirmNavigationRequest implements INavigationAware.  I'm asking about the NavigationContext that is passed into those methods, and if it's possible to detect if the user is navigating to a new page or backwards to the previous page.

Comment: Simply said, No. I looked through the the navigation chapter and I cant seem to find anything that detects wether you used GoBack or GoForward. But ofcourse there are the 'dirty' ways of doing so.